# What is the best or ideal approach to creating routes in node for production application?

Tags: node.js

Is it to create a single js file, then put every possible combination of routes for each verb like so:

```
myRoutes.js:

app.get('/', ...)
app.get('/students', ...)
app.get('/teachers', ...)
```

OR create something like this one below which is quite confusing for some beginner like me?

```
students.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = () => {
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('In students file');
});
}

teachers.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = () => {
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('In teachers file');
});
}

index.js:
const express = require('express');
const studentsRoute = require('./students');
const teachersRoute = require('./teachers');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = () => {
router.get('/',(req,res) => {
 res.send('In home directory');
});
}

router.use('/students', studentsRoute());
router.use('/teachers', teachersRoute());
```

What's a bit confusing is the router.get with '/' on both students and teachers file because '/' denotes HOME page, but in each of those files, there is this router.use('/students'...) and router.use('.teachers'...), so does the router.use supersede the router.get, and this is the ideal approach of structuring node folder and files in a real-world scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split your routes by common path ex. `/api/students`

```
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const app = express()
app.use('/api', routes)

// routes/index.js
const { Router } = require('express')
const studentsRouter = require('./students')
const router = Router()
router.use('/students', studentsRouter)
module.exports = router

// routes/students.js
const { Router } = require('express')
const api = Router()
api.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('In students file')
})
module.exports = api
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can paste desired middleware for particular route `/api/students/100` or route group `/api/students` or whole app `/api`

You can go even further and try to implement Controllers and Services pattern.

```
// routes/students.js
const { Router } = require('express')
const StudentsController = require('../controllers/students')
const api = Router()
api.get('/:id', StudentsController.getOne)
module.exports = api

// controllers/students.js
const studentsService = require('../services/students')
class StudentsController {
  static getOne(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id
    const student = studentsService.getOne(id)
    res.send(student)
  }
}

// services/students.js
class StudentsService {
  constructor() {
     // initialize with some parameters
  }
  getOne(id) {
     // get from database a student with id
  }
}
const studentsService = new StudentsService()
module.exports = studentsService
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, looks good I just need to understand some parts a bit, but does app.use('/url_value') supersede app.get('/')?